# IdentityServer DB Location

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, identityserver4

I am following a tutorial on Identity Server.  I reached the point where it creates the necessary database objects.

This worked, however I cannot figure out where this database has been created.

This is the bit I'm up to:

http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/6_aspnet_identity.html#creating-the-user-database

I'm using Visual Studio 2017

Thanks in advance

Comment: chances are with all the "locslhosdt" its on your pc.. you should be able to see that with sql management studio

Comment: it will be a local db check your project directory there should be a MDF file

Comment: Thats what I thought, but there is nothing in the solution. Its a .Net Core app if it makes any difference.
There is a Data folder but it just contains a few classes.

Comment: Found it, it was an MDF file placed within the Users\<ProfileName>\ directory